# Unable to find package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Tags: c#, .net, package

I am struggling with a project I just created on Visual Studio 2019. It's a .net C# project.
When I launch the project I get this error :

"Unable to find package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. No
packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
Packages"

I have tried to install the package but it doesn't work. And I have the package already installed as you can see here :

[image]

What do you think I should do ?

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue.
You need to change your package sources, as shown in the image.
=> Tools >> NuGet Package Manager >> package sources then click at "+" and add : name: nuget.org.
source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

[image]

Comment: better to use https protocol

Answer (score 2):

My problem apparently was that I only had Offline Packages as a source, so I added nuget too and VS was able to get the package from it.

[Nuget package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRZkB.png)

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Answer (score 0):

It's true. `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` does not exist in the `Offline Packages`

So search for a replaceable package that covers your needs or
you can **change the Package source to e.g `All` or whatever source you prefer**

[image]

**UPDATE**

adding the package to your `Offline Packages` will solve it also.

- Download package [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/)
- Update the `Offline Packages`

  => Tools >> NuGet Package Manager >> Package Manager Settings.

  => Packages Sources tap > select the `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages` => set the path => add the downloaded package.

  => click update.

And you can check or update the `Offline Packages` path.
`Windows`

Go to

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config`
- in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config` file
- key `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'

Comment: I know how to get to the packages Sources and select Visual Studio Offline Packages but I can't find the path to the downloaded package. Could you help me with this by showing me on images ?

Comment: I also get these errors when I try to download the package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore : "No packages exist with this ID in source : Package source" and "Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project : '...'."

Comment: @YoussefKharoufi from `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config` file named Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Comment: I get the same error even tho I added that path to the package sources