# Unable to create new webapi project

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, nuget-package, .net-7.0

I am creating my first ASP.NET Core Web API project using .NET Core, but when I create my project in PowerShell using command

```
dotnet new webapi -n FirstProject
```

The template "ASP.NET Core Web API" was created successfully.

```
Processing post-creation actions...
Restoring D:\Applications Setup\FirstProject\FirstProject.csproj:
  Determining projects to restore...
D:\Applications Setup\FirstProject\FirstProject.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Open
Api. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\librar
y-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
D:\Applications Setup\FirstProject\FirstProject.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. N
o packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\library-pack
s, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
  Failed to restore D:\Applications Setup\FirstProject\FirstProject.csproj (in 125 ms).
Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'
```

I have also installed the latest version of .NET sdk. Why I am getting this error? Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: can [this question](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/8026) help you? If you have installed VS, you may try to change your [package sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135695)